# Query RSS feeds

Tags: php, xml, rss, atom-feed

I have generated the RSS feeds successfully.

Now the problem is, XML output is coming out very well in Mozilla Firefox browser. But when it comes to Google Chrome, output is displaying with NO XML tags. And also when I tried in IE 8, it's throwing an error like "Internet Explorer cannot display this feed".

Please suggest, how this can be handled.

Comment: whats the fee look like?

Comment: Can you show us what the XML output is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validators are your friend here - at least a better friend than browsers. Run your feed through [an RSS validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/), and if it passes, you're probably fine.

- **Firefox** - displays a [parsed XML structure](http://www.evilgeniuschronicles.org/wordpress/2007/03/17/xml-view-in-mozilla/) when pointed at an XML document.
- **Chrome** - doesn't attempt to [show an XML structure](https://superuser.com/questions/972/displaying-xml-in-chrome-browser), you'll just see the text without any tags (which is what you're seeing).
- **Internet Explorer** - Not sure about IE8, google says it's supposed to show feeds, but there are [plenty of results](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22Internet+Explorer+cannot+display+this+feed%22.#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=%22Internet+Explorer+cannot+display+this+feed%22&aq=f&aqi=g2g-v2g-o1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.1,or.&fp=2ce4b7de8d5212a) for the error you're getting.

Use the validator and if there are errors, it will tell you.